# Forcing images to be displayed at actual size in Mathematica

Tags: wolfram-mathematica

When right clicking an `Image` in the front end, there's the option to display at its actual size (i.e. 1:1 screen to image pixel size).

How can images be forced to be shown like this?  When making a `Row` or `Column` of `Image`s, how can they be made to display at their actual size?

<sup>I was comparing image resampling methods to see which one gives the best result for a sharp edges when this came up.  As a workaround I `ImageAssemble`d all the images, so I had to right-click only once to get them to display at actual size.</sup>

Comment: Congratulations on 6000 rep. :-)

Comment: It's an art getting precisely at a 1k multiple

Comment: Thanks :-)  What a long discussion you had here while I was away :-) !

Answer (score 6, accepted):

Here is another method that works on version 7 at least.

```
img = ExampleData[{"TestImage", "Lena"}];

Row[{ Image[img, Magnification -> 1], Image[img, Magnification -> 1] }]
```

Comment: This works for me. I was wondering about the identical `Image[...]` calls, but then I realized that in a Row mma would automatically downscale them. This shows the Magnification at work. Now you get my +1

Comment: For future reference, *[`Image[obj,options]` gives an image that uses the specified options](http://reference.wolfram.com/mathematica/ref/Image.html)*, i.e. `Image[Image[...], ...]` is alright.

Comment: @Szabolcs, pardon me, but isn't that what I did above?

Comment: It is, which is why I wondered if a more complex use of `Image[Image[]]` could change or damage the image in any way (e.g. re-rasterize).  The answer: it doesn't and it is safe.  I thought the comment may be useful for others. When you posted originally, I included the `Magnification -> 1` in the original code generating the image.  Now I needed to change existing images.

Answer (score 3):

I only became aware of this context menu item a couple of months ago. It was probably added somewhere in v8.

I noticed `Image`-like output gets this item in their context menu, but bitmaps from `Rasterize` don't. You may try `Rasterize[Plot[Sin[x], {x, -\[Pi], \[Pi]}], RasterSize -> 500]` to test that. Put `// Image` behind it and you get a different context menu for the result.

I believe the presence of `ImageSize` in the containing *Cell* determine the scaling of images (of the second kind). No `ImageSize` means automatic scaling and `ImageSize->Magnification[1]` means actual size. So, you would need to manipulate the cell itself to change the behaviour.

Comment: Version 7 shows the context menu, and it works for `Image`s independently.

Comment: Mr.Wizard OK, couldn't check as I don't have 7 installed anymore. It's good that some still have it ;-)

Answer (score 2):

Please try:

```
Show[image, ImageSize -> All]
```

Likewise:

```
Row[{ Show[img1, ImageSize -> All], Show[img1, ImageSize -> All] }]
```

Comment: `Show[Rasterize[Plot[Sin[x], {x, -\[Pi], \[Pi]}], RasterSize -> 1000],  ImageSize -> All]` doesn't seem to compel mma to display the raster at 1000 pixels of width.

Comment: The description of `ImageSize->All` in the docs (i.e., "size that fits all objects in a collection") apart from being vague doesn't suggest "actual size" to me.

Comment: @Sjoerd, fortunately for me, he wrote `Image` not `Graphics`. ;-p  (Seriously, this works just fine for `Image` objects on v7; it even shows the correct context menu item selected.)

Comment: Anyway, you might try the following: `img = ExampleData[{"TestImage", "Lena"}];` then `Show[img]` and `Show[img, ImageSize -> All]`. Only the former renders the image at its actual size.

Comment: @Sjoerd, no, I repeat: **this works correctly on my system** and `Show[img, ImageSize -> All]` **has the correct context menu item selected**.  It is disappointing that this behavior was apparently changed.

Comment: Did you really try with this image? I noticed that for the `{"TestImage", "Girl"}` the results differ. Has to do with the different sizes they have.

Comment: @Sjoerd, yes, of course I tried it with that image.  I have more respect for you than to assume that I know better than you do.  In fact I usually assume the opposite.

Comment: In `~` notation: Almost, but not quite, entirely unlike assuming usually the opposite

Comment: Thanks for your trust. That's mutual.  It must be a version difference then. Would be nice if others could confirm this. I sent you an email with some screendumps.

Comment: @Sjoerd I get the same results as you do. Mma 8.01 on Win$.

Comment: @belisarius There's a line from a TV show I am going to try to find to respond to that. :->

Comment: @Mr. You may respond with any cliché. I don´t have the slightest idea about the logical result of my construction :)

Comment: I also noticed that `img` and `Show[Image]` get different context menus. The former gets a `True` on `ImageQ`, the latter a `False`.

Comment: Indeed, your emailed pictures show a fundamentally different response between 7 and 8.

Comment: @belisarius I finally found what I was looking for, at 0:21 in this video: http://www.youtube.com/watch?v=A9OdQ9xv5TU

Comment: @Mr. `"following-still-you-not"` :D